# Google Data Studio: Show users for certain URL-path

Tags: regex, google-analytics, looker-studio, re2

I want to show and compare usertraffic from *Google-Analytics* in *Data Studio*. I need to break up the traffic between localized versions of our page.

**Pages Paths and user groups**
The basic language is German and hosted on [www.domain.ltd/](http://www.domain.ltd/). The URL-path for english content is [www.domain.ltd/en/](http://www.domain.ltd/en/) and for polish content we use the URL [www.domain.ltd/pl/](http://www.domain.ltd/pl/).
I want separate the user-traffic for each language-path and compare it in a *linear diagram*.

**RegEx**
I set up a new field with RegEx:

```
case
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page, '^.*garbe-industrial\\.de\\/en\\/.*') THEN "Tarffic EN"
WHEN REGEXP_MATCH(Page, '^.*garbe-industrial\\.de\\/pl\\/.*') THEN "Tarffic PL"
else "Tarffic DE"
end
```

I combined the new field to a linear diagram. The diagram does not show any data.

I tried different approaches:
RegEx: `.*\/en\/.*` instead of the donain-path-version (1)

--
(1) Update: changed the format to "code" in order to make the full RegEx visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder if your regular expression is too specific in the code example. I would think that just putting in `.*/en/.*` and `.*/pl/.*` would work to capture those pages. I do something similar for our Spanish pages. This works on my pages:

```
case when regexp_match(page, '.*/es/.*') then "Spanish"
else "English"
end
```

Comment: Did this not work? It looks like the asterisks got removed from the text. You would need to have .*/pl/.* to capture everything before and after that part of the URL.

Comment: Yes, this works. I did  some additional steps: I deleted the diagram and made shure, the new field is also used for "break down" 

`case 
when regexp_match(Seite, '.*/en/.*') then "Traffic EN"
when regexp_match(Seite, '.*/pl/.*') then "Traffic PL"
else "Traffic DE"
end`

@Reid Dossinger - I did not vote it down Reid